# Angular Essentials not working in VS Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I have installed it and when I right click i see it in the context menu.

But clicking on it doesn't do anything.

On another computer I even dont see Schematics at all. Any idea?

I got it from here:
[Link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.angular-essentials)

Here is how it looks:

[image]

But when I click on Schematics nothing happens.

Comment: could you please write your question in details??

Comment: Edit my question.

Comment: Did you restart your ide?

Comment: Many times, I even reinstalled VS code and added Extensions again. The same.

Comment: I deleted everything from .vscode\extensions folder and tried to install Essentials again. It opened the IDE and nothing else. The extensions folder is still empty.

Comment: While keeping IDE open I clicked on the Install from the above link again. This time I got a prompt to install Essentials. The extensions folder has a bunch of files now. But context menu is not showing Schematics. Does it have anything to do with the project I have opened in the IDE?